# Android: playing video in picture-in-picture mode ( multiple instances when click on close button)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

For my android application, when a user play a video, a new activity (VideoPlay) starts in pip mode.

Manifest (Video Play)

```
<activity
            android:name=".PlayVideo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:configChanges=
            "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"/>
```

The problem is when i click on close button "X" of the pip screen, a new instance of my app is created.

how to handle this problem ? thank you

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not another instance of your app, but rather a different task which houses your `PlayVideo` activity. To prevent showing your activity in recents screen, you can add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the manifest attributes of your `PlayVideo` activity.

Also, if you're force closing your `PlayVideo` activity in some way other than user interaction like backpress, you may like to call `finishAndRemoveTask()` instead of just `finish()` as calling `finish()` will not remove your activity from recents.